# React - can I set state with different type of data?

Tags: reactjs

Example, I have a state call 'score', it has initial value '-'

```
const [score,setScore] = useState('-')
```

I then will set its value in somewhere:

```
setScore(100)
```

It works no doubt, but just curious, can I do in this way?
or should I keep the initial value with the same type, eg: Number here?

```
const [score,setScore] = useState(-1)
```

Then render the html with additional adjustment on value if value -1 then show as '-'

Answer (score 0):

You can do it.
If you want type-safe code, you can use typescript with react.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works because useState will completely replace the old state with new state. It always prefer to use the initial state the same type with your "future" state to avoid unexpected outcomes when you modify the state between rendering.